# An access Problem : how to show a report in maximize form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have created a form in access 2010, in which there is a show report button.Whenever a user 
clicked that button it show a report.

Now I want that this report is always visible in maximize form.
I have checked report property but there is no such option.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you would need to do this with VBA. Microsoft has published an article about '[How to Use Visual Basic for Applications to Minimize, Maximize, and Restore Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210090)'. This should be able to do exactly what you want. They even provide code examples for you. Other than the button, you would need to do it on the load of the report.

Comment: But i want it when pdf icon is clicked,report is open and it should be in maximize format. i have this code,it is partial. Private Sub Command41_Click() DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewReport, , StrQuery

Comment: Does a PDF display inside Access or outside Access in your PDF viewer? If the latter, you'll have to use API calls to find the PDF viewer window and maximize it.